# SFDX create definition from a dev org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

I am wondering if there is a way to create the sfdx scratch org definition straight from a dev org. i am aware of shape and snapshot however these are in pilot and what i am hoping for is something that would connect to a old dev org get the definition for this org and store it so i can use it for my scratch orgs.